# Create conditions that find me a similarity percent between the two elements

Tags: python, list, optimization, compare, percentage

I have an item list that I would like to compare with the input value. 
However, I would like to make a comparison with a percentage of equality between the two elements. 
For example :

```
var1 = "Minion (2015)"
var2 = "Minion <2015)"
```

With a SequenceMatcher method, i have a return value who is : **0,92 (92%)**

My goal is to create a condition that will find me if there is a similarity between the two elements from **70%**.

Here is my values :

```
MyInput = 'Minion (2015)'
list2 = ['minion (2015)', 'minion (2016)', 'minion (2017)', 'minion (2018)', 'minion (2019)']
```

*list2 is an extract of my CSV file to convert a list.

My script

```
import csv
import itertools

filepath = 'C:XXXXXXXX\myFile.csv'

MyInput = str(raw_input().lower())

fileCSVReader = csv.reader(open(filepath, 'r'))

list2 = list(fileCSVReader)

list3 = [str(x.lower()) for t in list2 for x in t]

# Part that i would like to evolve

if MyInput in list3:
    print 'found it'
else:
    print 'not found it'
```

I take any suggestions :)

Comment: What is the criteria for percentage? No of character matches order of characters or what?

Comment: common metric for string similarity that takes into account things like insertions and deletions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: @RajanChauhan Yes, it's about the order of characters as the example (see bellow) 
var1 = "Minion (2015)"
var2 = "Minion <2015)"

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, I'm assuming you need something like this [ignoring the case]

```
MyInput = 'Minion (2015)'
list2 = ['minion (2015)', 'minion (2016)', 'minion (2017)', 'minion (2018)', 'minion (2019)']
match_lst = []
for v in list2:
    if v.lower() == MyInput.lower():
        match_lst.append(v)

print (match_lst)
```

Output:

```
['minion (2015)']
```

Comment: Allright @Santhosh and i would like to have in output value, the element matching to 100% in the list, it's possible?

Comment: that should be simple if i understand you correctly. Updated.

Comment: Hum, i already understood this part. But, about the similarity percent, the condition if i enter the value for example "Minion <2015)", how to match with the list2 and to have an output value of the item matching? With the SequenceMatcher method, the result is 92%. So, i would like to have this item matching, the most reliable in output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nltk library for your purpose. The following code will basically tokenize the two strings and get the number of common terms between the two. The use of nltk here is that it takes into account additional combinations as well e.g. plurals or semantic similarity etc.

```
import nltk
import nltk.corpus
import nltk.tokenize
import nltk.stem.snowball
import string

stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
stopwords.extend(string.punctuation)
stopwords.append('')
stemmer = nltk.stem.snowball.SnowballStemmer('english')

def get_match_ratio(s1, s2):
    tokens_s1 = [token for token in nltk.word_tokenize(s1.lower())]
    tokens_s2 = [token for token in nltk.word_tokenize(s2.lower())]
    stems_s1 = [stemmer.stem(token) for token in tokens_s1]
    stems_s2 = [stemmer.stem(token) for token in tokens_s2]

    ratio = len(set(stems_s1).intersection(stems_s2)) / float(len(set(stems_s1).union(stems_s2)))
    return ratio

MyInput = 'Minion (2015)'
list2 = ['minion (2015)', 'minion (2016)', 'minion (2017)', 'minion (2018)', 'minion (2019)']

similarity = [[item, get_match_ratio(MyInput, item)] for item in list2]
print similarity
```

Comment: After a long install about the nltk lib. The script works. But, just a last question @Anoop Sharma, how to have the output value who is matched? For example, after the result, the value returned 'minion (2015)' as the most reliable.

Comment: Yes nltk does take a long time to install. I have changed the code to get the value along with the match ratio. (Edited the second last line)

Comment: it's possible to retrieve the element associated about the similarity? The result will be "minion 2015" in output value.